# Geth(clique): Getting the total initial supply on a geth private network

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, clique, geth-clique, mastering-ethereum

Using ethers/web3 is it possible to get the total initial supply (which is predetermined on clique) so I can get a hold of the data and display it somewhere..

I know how to get the total supply of an ERC20 token but the total/initial supply of the main network - is this possible ?

Or do I need to look at block 0 ?

Anyone know how this could be done in the easiest way possible ?

Thanks in advance